# I need some assistance with this java overloading array

Tags: java, arrays, overloading

so for this assignment, I have to make a main method, inputArray method,selectionSort method, printArray method, and a binarSearch method. I have all of those in my assignment. The inputArray is for a scanner to inport 10 double numbers into an array. The selectionSort puts the double numbers for lowest to highest. The PrintArray prints the new Order. Then I have to ask the user to enter a search key(a double number) which the binarySearch method then tries to find(the search key double number) and tell you if it is or is not in the array list of 10 numbers. Here is what I have so far:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab11 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] numbers = new double[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter 10 double values:");
        for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
            System.out.println(inputArray());
        }
    }
    public static double[] inputArray(){
        System.out.print(">");
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    public static void selectionSort(double[] list){
        double temp;
        for(int i=0; i < (numbers.length-1); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < numbers.length; j++){
                if(numbers[i] < numbers[j]){
                    temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your Question???

Comment: Please be more specific and format better. Give us the output that you get. and the specific question would help too.

Comment: sorry the assignment is to long to copy. The program works like this. The program asks user to input 10 double numbers into array through scanner. Then it sorts the numbers from smallest to largest. Then it prints out the sorted numbers. Then the program askes user to enter a number. Then it tells you if the number is in the 10 numbers that the user first entered

Comment: I think he have a problem with his `numbers` variable it's not a static variable but a local variable of `main()`.

Comment: If you have no question and just want us to finish it, that won't happen.... But one issue that @FLefèvre was saying, that the `numbers` array is only in the scope of main which won't be  able to be used in any of your methods.

Comment: I am not asking for the exact answer, I just want to know how to solve it. All the method headers are right because that is what it calls for in the instructions. I did the method bodies, but I am not really sure how to organize them because it is overloading methods. I didnt start on the search method though because I wanted to know how to get the first part to work, which is the scanning of the 10 numbers and sorting them in accending order, then printing the number out in the new order

Comment: how would I fix it to where all methods can use the array? do I have to put it into each  method?

Comment: declare the array outside of your method scope, make it a class array? Right now you are declaring `numbers` array in the scope of main which means only in main can you use that array. if you declare it as a class variable then you can use it in your methods

Comment: Are you using an IDE ? It's usefull to understand some problems...

Comment: I am still kind of confused, do you have a Skype account that I could call you on there, and I could share screens or something. My teacher grades harshly and I don't think I can have a class dedicated to the array. My skype username is Lawmaan17 if someone could add me and help please. Thanks so much for helping. If not skype, I am still confused with what you are saying with the class.

Comment: IDE would help, but understanding OOP will help more.

Comment: I am using eclipse for java

Comment: Ok what eclipse say to you concerning `numbers` ? @TooTiredToDrink I agree ! :)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
 i cannot be resolved to a variable
 input cannot be resolved

 at lab11.inputArray(lab11.java:14)
 at lab11.main(lab11.java:9)

Comment: First things first. Try to correct these errors. You have some tips near line numbers. ;)

Comment: Anjula_Ranasinghe helped me with part A, and now I need help with part B, which is to add a binarySearch method to allow the program to ask the user a number. The user enters a number then the program tell the user if the answer is or is not in the list of 10 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with

```
package test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] numbers = new double[10];        
        System.out.println("Please enter 10 double values:");
        for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
            numbers[i] = inputArray();
        }
        System.out.println("sorting");
        print(selectionSort(numbers));

    }
    public static double inputArray(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(">");
        double d = input.nextInt();
        return d;
    }

    public static double[] selectionSort(double[] list){
        double temp;
        for(int i=0; i < (list.length-1); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
                if(list[i] < list[j]){
                    temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static void print(double[] arr){
        for(double d:arr){
            System.out.println(d);
        }

    }
}
```

The input was taken from the `inputArray()` the the returned value was taken to the array `numbers`.

Then I called `selectionSort(numbers)` . There i haven't changed anything. All yours.

Then I returned the list array back to the main method. With that passing it to the print method.  `print(selectionSort(numbers));`
There I printed the array.

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: O I am sorry, I am new to the site, and realized you changed the code, Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure thing. If the answer I provided correct?? This is how I understood you r problem.

Comment: It was in decreasing order because of me but I changed the i and the j in the sorting method and it works. Could you help me with the second part of the question?

Comment: Using the program you wrote for Part A as a starting point, add a binary search method to find the location of the key in the sorted array. Implement your search in a method with the following header:

Comment: public static int binarySearch( double[] list, double key )Your binarySearch method should return the location of the key within the list or -1 if the key is not in the list.

Comment: I chaned my original question, to the correct part A that you helped me with, and need help with part B. How do I invoke the binarySearch?

Comment: What you posted here is another question. You can not change your original question here. post it as another one. and close this one by marking this answer as correct. First you must try something and paste your code with the question.

Comment: There is a correct sign under the up / down vote. Click the correct sign. Open up another question. for the BST

Comment: I rolled back the question to the first edit.  @lawtonhself, never edit answers into questions, and one question at a time!